# WooCommerce: Adding custom template to customer account pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, account

I am attempting to add a custom page to the customers 'account' section, which will allow the user to edit their order. At present I have been able to set an end point for the url and pick it up, but I need to get WooCommerce to initiate the page layout and be able to set the template location.

The URL being called:

```
/my-account/edit-order/55/
```

This is in the **`functions.php`** file, with the end point set and template override:

```
// Working
add_action( 'init', 'add_endpoint' );
function add_endpoint(){
     add_rewrite_endpoint( 'edit-order', EP_ALL );
}

// need something here to check for end point and run page as woocommerce

// Not been able to test
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'custom_endpoint', 10, 5 );
function custom_endpoint($located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path){

    if( $template_name == 'myaccount/my-account.php' ){
        global $wp_query;
        if(isset($wp_query->query['edit-order'])){
            $located = get_template_directory() . '/woocommerce/myaccount/edit-order.php';
        }
    }

    return $located;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a working solution for **WooCommerce 2.6+** to extend and manipulate the **tabbed "My Account" page endpoints** (See [**this reference**](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/wiki/2.6-Tabbed-My-Account-page) at the end of this answer), so here it is what you can do to achieve this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_new_wc_endpoint' );
function custom_new_wc_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'edit-order', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
}

add_filter( 'query_vars', 'custom_query_vars', 0 );
function custom_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = 'edit-order';
    return $vars;
}

add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'custom_flush_rewrite_rules' );    
function custom_flush_rewrite_rules() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

// The custom template location
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_edit-order_endpoint', 'custom_endpoint_content' );
function custom_endpoint_content() {
    include 'woocommerce/myaccount/edit-order.php'; 
}
```

---

Then you will need, to Insert the new **Edit order** endpoint into the **My Account menu**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_my_account_menu_items' );
function custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    // Remove the orders menu item.
    $orders_item = $items['orders']; // first we keep it in a variable
    unset( $items['orders'] ); // we unset it then

    // Insert your custom endpoint.
    $items['edit-order'] = __( 'Edit Order', 'woocommerce' );

    // Insert back the logout item.
    $items['orders'] = $orders_item; // we set it back

    return $items;
}
```

---

> **Important:** You will need to **flush the rewrite rules** *(2 ways)*:
>
> - Go to the Permalinks options page and re-save the permalinks *(thanks to* [helgatheviking](https://stackoverflow.com/users/383847/helgatheviking)*)*
> - You can also disable/enable your theme.

References:

- [Tabbed My Account page *(WC 2.6+)*: Creating new endpoints](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/wiki/2.6-Tabbed-My-Account-page)
- [WooCommerce: Assigning an endpoint to a custom template in my account pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039616/woocommerce-assigning-an-endpoint-to-a-custom-template)
- [How to add a new endpoint in woocommerce *(old and incomplete)*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200382/how-to-add-a-new-endpoint-in-woocommerce)

Comment: To flush the rewrite rules you can also go to the Permalinks options page and re-save the permalinks.

Comment: @helgatheviking Always as a woocommerce good fairy :) … I will add this now. Thank you.