# Woocommerce add_endpoint_content is not retrieving the template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding online tracking to my theme in Wordpress (version 5.0.3) and Woocommerce (version 3.5.4).

What I've done is create a new template under the `myaccount` subdirectory in Woocommerce called `order-tracking.php` so the path to the file from the Child theme directory is `/woocommerce/myaccount/order-tracking.php`

I've written the code below in order to pull the content from `order-tracking.php` which for now is just a simple `<?php echo 'Working'; ?>` to verify it's working:

```
    /*
 * Adding Track Your Order Tab to My Account menu
 */
/**
  * Register new endpoints to use inside My Account page.
  */

 add_action( 'init', 'my_account_new_endpoints' );

 function my_account_new_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'tracking', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
 }

/**
  * Get new endpoint content
  */
 add_action( 'woocommerce_account_tracking_endpoint', 'tracking_endpoint_content' );
 function tracking_endpoint_content() {
     get_template_part('order-tracking');
 }
     /**
  * Edit my account menu order
  */

 function my_account_menu_order() {
    $menuOrder = array(
        'orders'             => __( 'Your Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
        'tracking'             => __( 'Track Your Order', 'woocommerce' ),
        'downloads'          => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-address'       => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-account'      => __( 'Account Details', 'woocommerce' ),
        'customer-logout'    => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
        'dashboard'          => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' )
    );
    return $menuOrder;
 }
 add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_account_menu_order' );
```

When on the website, I click on the backend and get the below picture:

[image]

I've also tried copying one of the existing templates from the `woocommerce/myaccount` plugin directory to see if there was something I needed to intiate via PHP but this had the same effect as above (no effect).

This leads me to believe I'm missing something on my `/*** Get new endpoint content */` section.

Thoughts? Criticisms? All are appreciated. Please and thank you!

Comment: [This related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051331/woocommerce-adding-custom-template-to-customer-account-pages/38057611#38057611) might should help you.

Comment: This did help. I’m going to write an answer and credit to the answer to that thread. Thanks for your help I appreciate it