# Custom my account endpoint in Woocommerce just for a specific user role

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, account

Following the woocommerce documentation, I added an endpoit to my-account page in woocommerce.

I want to make this endpoint visible only to a specific user role, lets say shop_manager.

Is there a way to redirect to a 404 page users who try to access directly that endpoint?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have already created a custom endpoint to my account section ([see this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598829/custom-my-account-new-menu-item-for-a-specific-user-role-in-woocommerce)), you can redirect all non allowed user roles to a specific page using `template_redirect` hook in this simple way:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'custom_endpoint_redirection' );
function custom_endpoint_redirection() {
    $allowed_user_role = 'administrator';
    $custom_endpoint   = 'my-custom-endpoint';

    if ( is_wc_endpoint_url($custom_endpoint) && ! current_user_can($allowed_user_role) ) {
        $redirection_url = home_url( '/404/' );

        wp_redirect( $redirection_url );
        exit;
    }
}
```

You need to specify your custom end point, your allowed user role and the url redirection.

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It could works.

---

Related:

- [WooCommerce - Assign endpoints to multiple custom templates in my-account page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38266608/woocommerce-assign-endpoints-to-multiple-custom-templates-in-my-account-page)
- [WooCommerce: Assigning an endpoint to a custom template in my account pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039616/woocommerce-assigning-an-endpoint-to-a-custom-template-in-my-account-pages/38056768#38056768)
- [WooCommerce: Adding custom template to customer account pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051331/woocommerce-adding-custom-template-to-customer-account-pages/38057611#38057611)
- [Custom my account new menu item for a specific user role in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598829/custom-my-account-new-menu-item-for-a-specific-user-role-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php and this is only for `administrator` user role, you can change it as per you -

```
function add_custom_my_account_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'shop_manager', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_my_account_endpoint' );

function add_custom_wc_menu_items( $items ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( $user && in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ){
        $items[ 'shop_manager' ] = __( 'Shop Manager', 'text-domain' );
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_custom_wc_menu_items' );

function add_shop_manager_endpoint_content(){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if( $user && !in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) return;
    echo "Your content goes here";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_shop_manager_endpoint', 'add_shop_manager_endpoint_content' );
```

After this just `flush_rewrite_rules` from Backend Settings > Permalinks. Thats it.

Comment: If an unprivileged user tries to access the endpoint directly, he does not see any error messages, what I asked is whether it is possible to redirect on page 404.

Comment: Then just add a `if-else` logic and for unpriviledged user redirect them to 404 pages like -
`if( $user && !in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
 global $wp_query;
   $wp_query->set_404();
   status_header( 404 );
   get_template_part( 404 ); exit();
} else{
 echo "Your content goes here";
}`