# Display a Tab on the woocommerce my account page conditionally

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, conditional-statements

Hello I was able to create a custom endpoint on the woocommerce my account page:

```
    function my_custom_my_account_menu_items( $items ) {
    $items = array(
        'dashboard'         => __( 'Dashboard', 'woocommerce' ),
        'orders'            => __( 'Orders', 'woocommerce' ),
        //'downloads'       => __( 'Downloads', 'woocommerce' ),
        //'edit-address'    => __( 'Addresses', 'woocommerce' ),
        //'payment-methods' => __( 'Payment Methods', 'woocommerce' ),
        'edit-account'      => __( 'Edit Account', 'woocommerce' ),
        'special-page'      => 'Special Page',
        'customer-logout'   => __( 'Logout', 'woocommerce' ),
    );

    return $items;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_custom_my_account_menu_items' );
```

I visited the following urls:
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/2.6-Tabbed-My-Account-page
[WooCommerce: Assigning an endpoint to a custom template in my account pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039616/woocommerce-assigning-an-endpoint-to-a-custom-template-in-my-account-pages)

Now I would like to know how I can display a tab conditionally based on the user role? 
I would like to display the "Special Page" tab only for vendors.

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'vendor' ) ) {}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Nicholas

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code, but to work you need to call this part when the current_user is defined.

```
add_action('plugin_loaded', 'vendor_menu_items');

function vendor_menu_items(){
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'vendor' ) ) {
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_custom_my_account_menu_items' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the user role conditional around the add_filter statement or inside the function body itself. It doesn't really matter in this case because it's a fast check.
Here's the full code for adding an endpoint to the woocommerce my-account page:

```
// either use this line if you're writing a plugin
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'flush_rewrite_rules');
// or use this line if you're writing a theme
add_action('switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules');

add_action('init', 'my_add_rewrite_endpoints');
function my_add_rewrite_endpoints() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('vendor', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'my_my_account_menu_items');
function my_my_account_menu_items($menu_items) {
    // remove items this way
    unset($menu_items['downloads']);
    unset($menu_items['edit-address']);
    unset($menu_items['payment-methods']);

    // add items this way
    if(current_user_can('vendor')) {
        $menu_items['vendor'] = __('Your vendor page', 'your-plugin-domain-name');
    }

    return $menu_items;
}

// note the key you used for $menu_items in the previous function must be in the name of this filter hook.
add_filter('woocommerce_account_vendor_endpoint', 'my_vendor_endpoint');
function my_vendor_endpoint() {
    echo '<p>Your page content here</p>';
}
```